# YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query : Authentication to associated channel

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api, google-sheets-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have managed to arrange the sample code available in the google app script document; to retrieve data from my associated YouTube channel.

```
function myFunction() {
  var channelId ={MY ASSOCIATED CHANNEL ID};
  // Set the dates for our report
  var today = new Date();
  var oneMonthAgo = new Date();
  oneMonthAgo.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 1);
  var todayFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(today, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
  var oneMonthAgoFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(oneMonthAgo, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
//query
  var analyticsResponse = YouTubeAnalytics.Reports.query(
    'channel==' + channelId,
    oneMonthAgoFormatted,
    todayFormatted,
    'views,likes,dislikes,shares',
    {
      dimensions: 'day',
      sort: '-day'
    });
//output
Logger.log(analyticsResponse)
}
```

Am not sure about, how to authenticate the script to my associated channel.

Could you please help to correct the code.

Thanks,

Aneesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to menu Resources -> Advanced Google Services
2. Switch on Youtube Analytics
3. Go to Google Developers console (at the bottom of the window there is the link) or click here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library
4. Click on YouTube Analytics API
5. Click ENABLE

PS: Make sure you're using the script that is owned by the gmail account associated with the channel.